# If zh represents a /ʒ/ sound, then could gh represent a /dʒ/ or <j> sound?

Tags: orthography

The sound zh represents a voiced sh sound in Pinyin. The sound ch represents an unvoiced j. So, I was thinking that, because g is a voiced c (unless it is before an e or an i, and it should be a k, but I'm being flexible with the orthography), we could make gh a "j" sound. Is that true?

Comment: In Italian and Romanian, <g> is [dʒ] before <e> and <i>, but it's [g] otherwise. In order to write syllables [ge] and [gi], an <h> is inserted between the <g> and the vowel, so in Italian and Romanian [ge] and [gi] are written as <ghe> and <ghi>, cf. Italian nouns _Lambor**gh**ini_ [lamborˈ**ɡ**iːni] and _**gh**etto_ [ˈ**ɡ**etːo]. My point is Italians and Romanians will hardly appreciate using <gh> for [dʒ].

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're talking about Hanyu Pinyin, the system used to romanize Mandarin, *zh* doesn't represent a voiced version of *sh*. *Zh* is instead the "voiced" (unaspirated) version of *ch*, a retroflex affricate. In general, though, yes, *zh* is often used to represent `/ʒ/`, e.g. in romanized Russian.

As for this part, though:

> we could make gh a "j" sound. Is that true?

Sure! If you're designing a new romanization, you're allowed to do whatever you want. There are writing systems in active use that use *y* for `/ʑ/` and *w* for `/ɣ/` (Yi pinyin), or use *c* and *q* for click consonants (isiZulu and other Bantu languages that have clicks). The Cherokee syllabary uses *Ꮃ* for `/la/`, *Ꭲ* for `/i/`, and *Ꭼ* for `/gə/`.

Will it be easily understandable to English-speakers? Probably not. English-speakers are used to *gh* being pronounced either as `/g/` or as `/ɣ/`, definitely not as `/dʒ/`, and linguists will generally expect either `/ɣ/` or `/gʱ/`.

So it all comes down to your use-case. There's no law stopping you from using *gh* to transcribe any sound you want; the question is just whether people will understand it, and the answer to that is "probably not". If you care about this, I would recommend something like *dzh* instead.

(If your use case is something like "I want to give my students a worksheet on Old English, but am limited to ASCII for technical reasons", on the other hand, replacing *ċ* and *ġ* (the standardized Old English spelling for `/tʃ dʒ/`) with *ch* and *gh* might be perfectly fine.)

Comment: You're right. I was just thinking about a semantic writing problem. This could probably work in very special circumstances, like teaching Old English. I was also thinking because g is the voiced version of k (or c).

Comment: @MittenFile What do you mean by a "semantic writing problem"?